# Can't mount ISO file as loop device: Error: “failed to setup loop device”

Tags: mount, filesystem, cd, loop-device

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/cdrom
cd ~
sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-* /
mount: ubuntu-*: failed to setup loop device: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What did you expect? You created (as `root`) a directory, then changed directory to the HOME directory of the logged-in user, then tried to mount the wildcard `ubuntu-*` over the root directory. The wildcard `ubuntu-*` did not match anything in the current directory, and `mount` told you. What were you trying to do?

Answer (score 15):

First make sure you have mounted loop device kernel module. So run:

```
lsmod | grep loop
```

If you get no output, that means you have to mount the loop device kernel module . So:

```
modprobe loop
```

Re-run the following to make sure the module is loaded. You should get some outputs:

```
lsmod | grep loop
```

Now, to mount an ISO file as loop device do the following:

```
mount -o loop -t iso9660 <path/to/iso/file> /media/cdrom
```

However I guess it should also work without the `-t iso9660` part.

Comment: `modprobe loop` produces no output, is that the expected behavior? Even after that, there is no output for `lsmod | grep loop`.

Comment: Check that you have the `/dev/loop0` device and that you have permissions to use it. Use `--privileged` if you try this in Docker.

Comment: I have the `/dev/loop0` and I am running this after `sudo -i` but still no output after doing `modprobe loop`.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you're blindly following some instructions on how to mount an Ubuntu ISO image using the loop device.

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/cdrom
```

This creates a directory `cdrom` owned by root in `/media` if not existing, and it's meant to be used as the to be mounted filesystem's mount point;

```
cd ~
```

This changes the current working directory of your terminal instance to `~`, which is a shorthand which expands to your home directory's path;

```
sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-* /
```

This attempts to mount all the files matching `ubuntu-*` (all the files having a filename starting with `ubuntu-`) in your home directory using the loop device and `/` as the mount point. Just don't do that. It's not useful at all to match against a wildcard if you're trying to mount a single ISO image, leaving aside that fact that you want your `/` mount point to keep holding the root partition. Mount the ISO image specifying its exact filename and mount it on the mount point you just created (`/media/cdrom`). In order to do that, make sure that the ISO image you want to mount is present in your home directory and change `ubuntu-*` with the full name of the ISO image. For example, to mount the official image of Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.2 64-bit the command would be:

```
sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso /media/cdrom
```

Answer (score 0):

This mounted my file for me

sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso /media/cdrom

Thanks kos

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that the this is not a direct answer to the OP's question. however I decided to drop an answer because this post was a high ranked result when I googled about my own situation.

In my case running as a non-root user caused the following error:

```
failed to setup loop device for /home/user/ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso
```

Don't forget to run mount command with root privileges.
You can run it with sudo for example.

Comment: This does not answer the question. In the question, they clearly have the `sudo` part correct

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you @DanielT for your advice. I googled my error message (the one that is included in my answer) and this question was a high rank result. I noticed that the OP has already used sudo to run with high privileges but I decided to put an answer to help those who might be redirected here (just like me)